# android robotium second test get stuck

Tags: android, robotium

Using robotium to run the automated tests. There are two tests, if I run each of these independently it works fine to successful completion. If the tests are run one of the other by selected to run all the tests in the module, the first test runs, the second test starts but the first fragment never get rendered properly and the test fails. Here is the line of code 
from which here is failing.

`getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, threadF,(String) args.get(DispatchController.fragment_tag)).commit();`

The exception is that thrown.

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState`

Comment: RCA: The android activity instance was stored in dispatchcontroller, and the first test was destroyed but since dispatchcontroller was a singleton it was still holding on to the  stale object instance which prevented the second test case from running.  So this a application error.

Comment: Can you post full code of test classes? You can remove some unnecessary or sensitivities code.